# Como armazenar os nomes de uma tabela em um Vetor no R

Tags: r

Preciso armazenar os nomes de uma tabela em um vetor, pois vou precisar fazer combinações com os nomes. Segue um exemplo para entendimento:

Tabela:

```
Carro  preço  cor
Gol   15000  vermelho
uno   14000  azul
corsa 13000  verde
```

vetor que eu quero no final:

```
Vetor --> (Carro,preço,cor)
```

Vou trabalhar com tabelas com muitas colunas, que vai mudar de nome muitas vezes, então preciso de um código para deixar automático a criação do vetor.

Answer (score 5):

Os nomes de uma tabela podem ser acessados com a função `names()`.

```
nomes <- names(Tabela)

nomes
# [1] "Carro" "preço" "cor"
```